# Android rotating one bitmap around another

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, rotation, 2d

Im making a 2d game where my character is controlled by a joystick and I rotate him using `canvas.rotate(angel, x, y)`. My character shoots in the same direction he is heading, now I want to add fire coming out of his rifle when he shoots. The problem is, how do I rotate this fire-image around my character?

How I rotate My character:

```
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate((float) controls.getAngle(), controls.charPosition.x + charBitmap.getWidth() / 2, controls.charPosition.y + charBitmap.getHeight() / 2);
    character.draw(canvas, controls.charPosition.x,controls.charPosition.y);
    canvas.restore();
```

How I rotate the Fire:

```
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate((float) controls.getAngle(), controls.charPosition.x + (fireBitmap.getWidth()) / 2, controls.charPosition.y + (fireBitmap.getHeight() / 2));
        fire.draw(canvas, controls.charPosition.x, controls.charPosition.y);
        canvas.restore();
```

As you probably know, drawing my fire like this will make it rotate around its own center, just like with my character. But I want it to rotate **around** my character so it looks like the fire is coming out of his gun.

Any ideas? If anything is unclear please let me know in a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Canvas.translate(dx, dy)`. Idea is to move the fire a certain distance away from the gun, which can be directly along x -axis, and then rotate Canvas around gun center. This results fire to rotate given angle at given distance from the gun.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate((float) controls.getAngle(), controls.charPosition.x + (fireBitmap.getWidth()) / 2, controls.charPosition.y + (fireBitmap.getHeight() / 2));
canvas.translate(distanceFromGun, 0);
fire.draw(canvas, controls.charPosition.x, controls.charPosition.y);
canvas.restore();
```

Please do note the order. Canvas matrix operations are pre multiplying and though translation is made later in the code.

Comment: this did the trick! Very simple and understandable solution. Thank you good sir!

Answer (score 2):

I will try to tailor this answer so that it's more specific, but if I understand you correctly, you may not want to rotate the canvas to create the rotation of the fire. Instead you may want to describe it with a trig function relative to the character's location. So I think it will look something like your drawing of the character.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate((float) controls.getAngle(), controls.charPosition.x + charBitmap.getWidth() / 2, controls.charPosition.y + charBitmap.getHeight() / 2);
fire.draw(canvas, controls.charPosition.x+(fireRadius*cos(fireAngle)),controls.charPosition.y+(fireRadius*sin(fireAngle));
canvas.restore();
```

Where in this code, fireRadius is how far from the center of the character drawing you want the fire drawing to be and fireAngle is the angle of the fire from the center of the character. This won't be quite right because it will track the corner of the fire image, not the center. I think that can be fixed somewhat easily. If not, I will change soon.